# Php Web Server Generic Cookie Injection

Tags: php, cakephp, pci-compliance

Got a website where a security scan for PCI compliance has comeback with a fail for the following:

Web Server Generic Cookie Injection

Impact The remote host is running a web server that fails to adequately sanitize request strings of malicious JavaScript. By leveraging this issue, an attacker may be able to inject arbitrary cookies. Depending on the structure of the web application, it may be possible to launch a 'session fixation' attack using this mechanism. Please note that : - SecurityMetrics did not check if the session fixation attack is feasible. - This is not the only vector of session fixation. See also : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation

I haven't been able to find much information about this error and gone round in circles about it.  I'm assuming it's an cakephp issue.

Cheers

Comment: Is there a question here? Also, can you clarify "request strings of malicious JavaScript". I don't know what that means.

Comment: It's clearly not an issue if the framework. I've worked on a gambling site who did PCI compliance tests as well. And no code, no help. This question is far to broad to be answered. The basic problem is that a 3rd party can inject something, somehow (guess through the cookie) into your app.

Comment: Hi @burzum thanks for your answer.  Someone else wrote the website for our client and it's been handed over to us with this issue which I've been asked to look at.